# Memory leak or memory fragmentation?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, c++builder, memory-fragmentation

I'm running following code in **Borland Builder C++ 6** and can see increasing memory used by the program in Memory (Private Working Set) , Windows Task Manager which, I believe is a memory leak.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{      
   try {
     int n = 0;
     int r = 1 / n; //division by zero
   }
   catch (EDivByZero& e) {}
}
```

I tried replacing default memory manager of Builder C++ with `FASTMM4` but see the same behavior. Is it because of **memory leak** or **memory fragmentation** because I'm confused between two. What I believe that in both cases, program has to page virtual memory to disk hence increasing the used memory.

Looking at virtual memory is a good idea to differentiate between leak and fragmentation but how can I do that? Is there a tool in windows to test it?

Comment: I tried the code in BCB2010 and the process memory doesn't increased not at all.

Comment: Thank you testing it and that's what my question is; if it's the problem in BCB6 and RTL/FASTMM is not releasing memory used for exception.

Comment: I used FastMM with BCB6 and it's leaking memory as well. I checked with FastMM reporting.

Answer (score 0):

' increasing memory used by the program in Memory (Private Working Set) , Windows Task Manager which, I believe is a memory leak.' - This is incorrect

When you free memory in your program it will be released back to your program, not to the O/S. Memory will only be released to the O/S when your program exits.

Note - this is only typical behaviour, C++ says nothing about explicitly about this, YMMV.

Comment: I'm actually talking about increasing memory used by the program in task manager only during this loop. When the loop starts, it is 1.580K and reaches to 5.880K. It also increases the number of Page Faults. Loop having any other arithmetic operation doesn't do so.

Comment: OK, well I guess the exception mechanism in Borland allocates memory (not too surprising). It doesn't make it a memory leak however.

Comment: Well you're right. I've tested it with raising some other exception and it behaves the same but when I use e.Free() in catch block, it doesn't increase used memory. Does it mean, we are clearing the memory used by exception? If yes, why doesn't Borland do this?

Comment: and also, every time i run the loop, it always increases the memory used by the program. Why do every time it needs new memory? Isn't because Builder C++ isn't releasing the memory used by exception some how and needs new memory every time or it is memory fragmentation?

Comment: "When you free memory in your program it will be released back to your program, not to the O/S" : This is icorrect.

Comment: You are in implementation defined behaviour here. I would be surprised if you are expected to explicitly free memory for exception objects, but if that's how Borland have designed things then you have to live with it.

Comment: @mhtaqia Could you elaborate?

Comment: Help documentation forbids to call Free() directly but borland itself isn't freeing it. I'm stuck with borland VCL source code (Delphi) looking for the reason.

Comment: @john If the freed memory does not return to OS, then we release allocated memory for Why?

Comment: @mhtaqia So your program can reuse it. The situation I described is the normal one. Freed memory is not returned to the OS, but it can be reused by the program. But as I said, the details do vary from OS to OS and from program to program. All I'm really saying is that if you free memory you cannot *guarantee* that memory will be available for another proess. That is only guaranteed when your process exits.

Comment: Manually freeing a caught exception is WRONG. Period. Don't do it. The RTL owns the memory, not you. VCL-based exceptions are allocated on the heap, and it is the responsibility of the RTL to free caught exceptions after the `catch` block exits. And BCB's RTL *does* free caught exceptions. So whatever you are experiencing is most likely NOT a memory leak, but you can use FastMM's memory leak capabilities to check that, since it knows everything it allocates and will tell you if any allocated memory was not freed.

Comment: And incidentally, DO NOT use `Free()` in C++. It is only for Delphi's use.  Use C++'s `delete` operator instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it is a memory leak. I just tested it with FastMM4 reportin. Now as it is leaking memory on every exception of EDivByZero, EAccessViolation or similar then should we just live with it or free it in catch block, C++ code? Why shouldn't we free it?

Comment: I have said it multiple times now. You **CANNOT** directly free a caught exception, unless you are the one who directly allocated it on the heap and then threw it. In the case of VCL exceptions, you **DO NOT** own the memory for them, the RTL does. It is the RTL's responsibility to free them. If the RTL is leaking VCL exceptions, then the RTL has a bug. With that said, I do use BCB6 myself, and I have never had a problem with the RTL leaking caught VCL exceptions. With that said, the simple answer is to avoid causing an exception in the first place. Check your input for 0 before dividing, etc.